# Lanzar un comando CURL a través de un script de Python

Tags: python, xml, post, curl

La intención es acceder a un servicio web que, mandándole unos datos por POST, devuelve una respuesta en formato XML (y ya, de paso, guardar ese XML en un archivo).

El correspondiente comando de CURL a ejecutar por la terminal sería el siguiente (en este caso, estoy queriéndolo hacer desde un equipo con Ubuntu 16.04 y con Python 2.7):

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/xml' -d '{ "content": "Esto es el contenido", "formato": "xxxx", "lang": "es" }' 'http://la-URL-destino.es' > archivo_respuesta.xml
```

Vale, ejecutando el comando de CURL por la terminal devuelve el XML y lo guarda en el archivo indicado para la salida (es decir, el "archivo_respuesta.xml").

La pregunta es ¿cómo conseguir lo mismo desde un script de Python? ¿algún ejemplo sencillo? ¿alguna librería o módulo que tuviera que instarla para ello?

Gracias por las posibles respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Desde python puedes lanzar cualquier programa del operativo, mediante `os.system()` o mediante funciones del módulo `subprocess` (por ejemplo `subprocess.call()`, que puedes usar para invocar directamente el comando `curl` que indicas. Si no quieres depender de `curl`, puedes usar la librería [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) que permite hacer peticiones HTTP (GET, POST, lo que quieras) de forma sencilla.

Comment: [Pycurl](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/) permite la interacción con libcurl directamente. También puedes usar [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) para lanzar el comanndo tal y como lo haces ahora, pudiendo modificar los argumentos en el propio script. [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) es otra alternativa a tener en cuenta y que también te va a permitir hacer la petición POST sin problemas.

Comment: @FJSevilla Nos hemos pisado (otra vez :-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ **CÓDIGO DEFINITIVO** ]

Bueno, tras probar ambas propuestas y hacer algunas adaptaciones y correcciones de alguno que ya había probado antes, aprovechando las propuestas mencionadas, el código me queda tal como sigue:

```
import requests


URL= 'http://la-URL-destino.es'
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/xml',
}
txt = 'Esto es el contenido.'
lang = 'es'
_format = 'xxxx'
data = '{"content": "' + txt + '", "format": "' + _format + '", "lang": "' + lang + '"}'
url_archivo_salida = 'archivo_respuesta.xml'

try:
    resp = requests.post( URL, headers = headers, data = data )

except Exception as e:
    print( 'La Exception >> ' + type(e).__name__ )
    raise e

else:
    #requests.codes.ok = 200 => OK
    if( resp.status_code == requests.codes.ok ):
        with open( url_archivo_salida, 'w' ) as f:
            f.write( resp.text )
            f.close()

    else:
        print( 'resp.status_code >> ' + str(resp.status_code) + ' != ' + str(requests.codes.ok) )
```

La cosa es que, en otras pruebas que había hecho con el *"requests"*, no había especificado, adecuadamente, las cabeceras que había que pasarle.

Otra cosa por la que me daba los errores expuestos en los comentarios de las propuestas es que la variable **data** aunque, internamente, está construida como un *JSON*, hay que pasarla como si fuera una cadena. Por eso, debe ir entre comillas y en una sola línea.

Answer (score 1):

Usando [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/):

```
import requests

json_a_enviar = { 
   "content": "Esto es el contenido", 
   "formato": "xxxx",
   "lang": "es" 
}
url = 'http://la-URL-destino.es'
cabeceras_extra = { 
   'Accept': 'application/xml' 
}
respuesta = requests.post(url, json=json_a_enviar, headers=cabeceras_extra)
with open("archivo_respuesta.xml", "w") as f:
   f.write(respuesta.text)
```

(Nota: no lo he probado pues la URL en cuestión no la tengo. Podrían aparecer problemas quizás con el encoding de la respuesta)

Comment: Hola ... La URL en cuestión es de un servidor interno de la empresa, una URL del estilo "http: // dnlp:8484/nombre-servicio". Y no sé si será por eso o por otra cosa que el resultado que me da es que el contenido que se escribe en el archivo_respuesta.xml es "Problem: null".

Comment: Para controlar la "respuesta", he puesto un `try: respuesta = requests.post(url, json=json_a_enviar, headers=cabeceras_extra) except Exception as e: print('La Exception >> ' + type(e).__name__) else: if( respuesta.status_code ==  requests.codes.ok ): with open("archivo_respuesta.xml", "w") as f: f.write(respuesta.text) else: print( 'respuesta.status_code >> ' + str(respuesta.status_code) )`, y entonces, el código HTTP que me da el else del try...exception es un 500 (Server Error), en vez de un 200 que es el de cuando la respuesta es OK. Entonces, ¿"requests" no funciona en un servidor interno?

Comment: @zacktagnan Requests funciona de la misma forma independientemente de si el servidor es interno o no. El error que te ha dado ha sido un error interno del servidor, lo que indica que al menos ha conseguido conectar con él y no es un problema de cortafuegos o proxies. El error 500 típicamente indica que el proceso que tenía que generar la respuesta en el servidor, "ha roto". Tiene pinta de que algún parámetro en el json que le envías, (o en las cabeceras) no es lo que el servidor esperaba. Tendrías que mirar los logs del servidor a ver por qué "ha roto".

Comment: @zacktagnan ¿Desde `curl` sí te funciona? Verifica que el JSON que usas en python es el mismo. Quizás ayudaría ver ese json (siempre que puedas hacerlo público)

Answer (score 1):

[`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) sin duda es uno de lo paquetes más útiles y hace mucho más simple todo, sin embargo tu inquietud también podría resolverse con la funcionalidad base de Python:

```
import httplib
import json

host    = 'nombre o ip del host'
port    = 8484
payload = json.dumps({"content": "Esto es el contenido", "formato": "xxxx", "lang": "es"})
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}

try:  
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host, port)
    conn.request('POST', '/post', payload, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
except Exception as e:
    print('Imposible conectarse al servicio: {0}'.format(e))
else:    
    with open("archivo_respuesta.xml", "wt") as f:
       f.write(response.read().decode())
    conn.close()
```

En este caso usaremos [httplib`][2] para abrir una conexión a la`url`indicada y generar un`request` con los datos mencionados.

Comment: Hola, como puse en al exponer la pregunta, la versión del Python que uso de forma predeterminada es la 2.7 ... por eso, parece que tengo que usar "httplib" que, según he leido buscando por Google, es el nombre anterior de "http.client" (nombre establecido para las versiones 3.x) ... Aparte de eso, y mencionando que el servicio web al que quiero acceder está dentro de un servidor interno cuya URL es del estilo "http: // dnlp:8484/nombre-servicio", el resultado que me da es una excepción con el mensaje "Imposible conectarse al servicio: nonnumeric port: '8484/nombre-servicio'"

Comment: También, he leido que al "httplib" no hay que especificarle la parte "http://" en el parámetro de la URL, por eso, solamente, he puesto " url = 'dnlp:8484/nombre-servicio' " ... pero sigue saliéndome el mismo mensaje de excepción mencionado. Entonces, ¿no es posible emplear el código que me sugieres con un servidor interno?

Comment: Por otro lado, aparte de obviar que duplcaste las líneas de "url= ... payload=... headers=...", a la de headers le añadí otro par ya que en el código de mi pregunta especificaba dos cabeceras, por ello, en esa línea, he puesto "headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/xml'}" Supongo que no hay problema por ello, ¿no?

Comment: @zacktagnan, edite mi respuesta para python 2.7, no vi etiqueta especifica y me dejé llevar por eso, de todas formas nos son muchos los cambios. Lo que sí es importante, es que veas la documentación de `HTTPSConnection()`, ya que se conecta de una forma más de bajo nivel, deberías pasar por un lado el `host` o `ip` y el `port` como otro parámetro, o eventualmente `host:port`. Con respecto a la forma de definir los `headers`, en los ejemplos documentación verás que se pasa directamente un diccionario y no una cadena como sugieres en tu último comentario.